# TypeOrm create connection method migration fails to create a table in the database

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to achieve schema based multi-tenancy using NestJS. I have a database connection created when app.module.ts file runs. Based on the configuration file it creates the table within the database. In my auth.service.ts I get encoded JWT token as bearer token. I decode the token and then do the following:

1. Get the existing database connection.
2. Create schema using tenantName_subTenantName (eg. abc_xyz) it gets created successfully
3. I close the database connection.
4. I try to create a new connection with new entity and migration that should only be created within the new schema.
5. I do not get any errors. But when I look into the database I see schema created but only migrations table added. The entity defined in entities array of connection option and setting migrationRun option true and synchronize option false and giving correct path to the migration file (at least what I think should be how the file path should be given). I still don't get the table connected.

**environment**

1. Mac OS X Big Sur version 11.2
2. Node.js version 13.13.0
3. Nestjs version 7.1.2
4. npm version 6.14.4
5. pg library version 8.5.1
6. typeorm library version 0.2.31

code:
orm.config.ts (File for my public database tables)

```
import { join } from 'path';
import { TenantInformation } from '../authentication/tenant-information.entity';

const OrmConfig = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT),
  username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
  synchronize: false,
  migrationsRun: true,
  entities: [TenantInformation],
  migrations: [join(__dirname, '../db/public/migrations/**/*{.ts,.js}',)],
  cli: {
    migrationsDir: 'src/db/public/migrations',
  }
};
export = OrmConfig;
```

tenant.orm.config.ts (File that contains migration and entities details for table that need to be created for tenants)

```
import { join } from 'path';
import { Points } from './entities/points.entity';

const TenantOrm = {
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT),
  username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
  synchronize: false,
  migrationsRun: true,
  entities: [Points],
  migrations: [join(__dirname, '../db-tenant/migrations/**/*{.ts,.js}',)]
}
export = TenantOrm;
```

app.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { OgmaModule } from '@ogma/nestjs-module';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

import { logConfig } from './config/log.config';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { TypeOrmConfig } from './config/typeorm.config';
import { AuthenticationModule } from './authentication/authentication.module';


@Module({
  imports: [OgmaModule.forRootAsync({
    imports: [ConfigModule],
    inject: [ConfigService],
    useFactory: logConfig
  }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: TypeOrmConfig
    }),
    AuthenticationModule,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

TypeOrmConfig file to create the first connection with schema as public schema and entities to be in the public schema

```
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { join } from 'path';
import { TenantInformation } from '../authentication/tenant-information.entity';

export const TypeOrmConfig = (configService: ConfigService): TypeOrmModuleOptions => ({
  type: 'postgres',
  host: configService.get('DB_HOST'),
  port: configService.get('DB_PORT'),
  username: configService.get('DB_USERNAME'),
  password: configService.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
  database: configService.get('DB_DATABASE'),
  synchronize: configService.get('DB_SYNCHRONIZE'),
  migrationsRun: configService.get('DB_MIGRATION_RUN'),
  entities: [TenantInformation],
  migrations: [join(__dirname, '../db/public/migrations/*{.ts,.js}')],
  cli: {
    migrationsDir: 'src/db/public/migrations',
  }
})
```

authentication.service.ts file contains logic to create a database schema and create a new connection and run migrations on the new connection for newly created schema.

```
async createTenantSchema(user: UserDto): Promise<void> {
    const { companyName, subClient } = user;
    const schemaName = subClient === '' ? companyName : `${companyName}_${subClient}`;
    const lowercaseSchemaName = schemaName.toLowerCase();
    this.logger.info(`Creating tenant connection for tenant schema ${schemaName}`);
    let connection: Connection;
    try {
      // connection = await this.createNewDatabaseConnection();
      connection = await getConnection();
    } catch(error) {
      this.logger.fatal(`Failed to get database connection. Error --- ${error}`);
      throw error;
    }
    try {
      await connection.manager.query(`CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ${lowercaseSchemaName}`);
    } catch(error) {
      this.logger.fatal(`Failed to create schema for tenant with schema name ${lowercaseSchemaName}. Error --- ${error}`);
      throw error;
    }
    try {
      await connection.close();
    } catch(error) {
      this.logger.fatal(`Failed to close connection after creating schema ${lowercaseSchemaName}. Error --- ${error}`);
      throw error;
    }
    try {
      await this.runDBMigrationsForSchema(lowercaseSchemaName);
    } catch(error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

```
async runDBMigrationsForSchema(schemaName: string): Promise<void> {
    this.logger.info(`Running database migrations on connection for schema ${schemaName}`);
    let schemaConnection: Connection;
    try {
      schemaConnection = await createConnection( {
        ...TenantOrm,
        name: schemaName,
        type: 'postgres',
        schema: schemaName,
      })
    } catch(error) {
      this.logger.fatal(`Failed to run database migration for schema ${schemaName}. Error --- ${error}`);
      throw error;
    }
    try {
      await schemaConnection.close()
    } catch(error) {
      this.logger.fatal(`Failed to close database connection after running database migration on schema ${schemaName}. Error --- ${error}`);
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

Migration schema file created in /src/db-tenant/migrations/1613408918381-points-table.ts

```
import {MigrationInterface, QueryRunner} from "typeorm";

export class pointsTable1613408918381 implements MigrationInterface {
    name = 'pointsTable1613408918381'

    public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(`CREATE TABLE "points" ("userPublicId" character varying NOT NULL, "companyPublicId" character varying NOT NULL, "points" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', "createdAt" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now(), "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT now(), CONSTRAINT "PK_97e2fe5d50f5a0d2dabc6eee6d7" PRIMARY KEY ("userPublicId"))`);
    }

    public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(`DROP TABLE "points"`);
    }

}
```

why is the migration not running? Or if the migration is running why I don't see a new table created in the database schema? I see new schema created but not the table.
Minimum Reproduction Repository:

```
https://github.com/vihangmi10/multi-tenancy-nestjs
```

Comment: which command do you are using to run migrations? tip: add a `console.log` on top of your migration file

Comment: Hello I tried using the following command : 
```
await schemaConnection.runMigrations();
```

Comment: I thought while creating the connection if migrationRun field is true it automatically detects the migration file from the location and runs the migration. Isn't it so ?

Comment: I think you're right. But ever you tried to use the CLI instead? following [the docs](https://typeorm.io/#/migrations/). Running `typeorm migration:show` will display all migrations.

Comment: I am seeing the following 
```
 bhyve-auth-service git:(develop) ✗ ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js -f src/config/orm.config.ts migration:show
query: SELECT * FROM "information_schema"."tables" WHERE "table_schema" = current_schema() AND "table_name" = 'migrations'
query: SELECT * FROM "migrations" "migrations"  ORDER BY "id" DESC
```
I am not sure why it is not showing migration to create new table.